# PL/SQL Triggers

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to make a Library Information System. I have a table called `Borrower(borrower_id: number, name: varchar2(30), status: varchar2(20))`. `'status'` can be either `'student'` or `'faculty'`.

I have a restriction that a maximum of 2 books can be issued to a student at any point of time, and 3 to a faculty. How do I implement it using triggers?

1. This is a homework question. But I've tried hard to come up with some logic. I am new to SQL so this might be easy for you lot but not for me.
2. I am new to stackexchange, so sorry if I've violated some rules/practices.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that you would maintain a count on the borrower table of the number of books borrowed, and modify it via a trigger when a book is borrowed and when it is returned. Presumably you also have a table for the books being borrowed by the user, and the trigger would be placed on that take.

A constraint on the books_borrowed column could raise an error if the count of borrowed books exceeds 2.

Comment: I am totally new to SQL. Could you please elaborate more on this? Really sorry for bugging you with stupid questions :/

Comment: I think maybe you misunderstood the question. The restriction is on a 'per-student' or 'per-faculty' basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but I found it very useful as I'm also a PL/SQL beginner. There are two approaches to solve the problem and the one you want to use depends on the Oracle DB version.

1. For older version use a combination of a trigger and a package as below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_borrower 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON borrower 
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE

    v_count NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
    v_count := borrower_pkg.count_rows(:NEW.borrower_id, :NEW.name, :NEW.status);

    IF :NEW.status = 'student' AND v_count = 2 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Error - student');

    ELSIF :NEW.status = 'faculty' AND v_count = 3 THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Error - faculty');

    END IF;

END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE borrower_pkg AS
    FUNCTION count_rows(p_id     IN borrower.borrower_id%TYPE,
                        p_name   IN borrower.NAME%TYPE,
                        p_status IN borrower.status%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY borrower_pkg AS

  FUNCTION count_rows(p_id     IN borrower.borrower_id%TYPE,
                        p_name   IN borrower.NAME%TYPE,
                        p_status IN borrower.status%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER AS

    v_count NUMBER := 0;

  BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count
        FROM borrower
    WHERE borrower_id = p_id AND NAME = p_name AND status = p_status;

    RETURN v_count;
  END count_rows;

END borrower_pkg;
/
```

2. For Oracle 10g and above you can use a compound trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_borrower_comp 
    FOR INSERT OR UPDATE ON borrower
    COMPOUND TRIGGER

    CURSOR c_borrower IS 
        SELECT b1.borrower_id
            FROM borrower b1
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' 
                        FROM borrower b2
                      WHERE b2.status = 'student' AND b1.borrower_id =  b2.borrower_id 
                        GROUP BY borrower_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2)
            OR 
              EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                        FROM borrower b3
                      WHERE status = 'faculty'AND b1.borrower_id =  b3.borrower_id
                        GROUP BY borrower_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 3);

    TYPE t_borrower_count IS TABLE OF borrower.borrower_id%type; 
    v_borrower_count t_borrower_count;

    BEFORE STATEMENT IS 
    BEGIN

        OPEN c_borrower;
        FETCH c_borrower BULK COLLECT INTO v_borrower_count;
        CLOSE c_borrower;

    END BEFORE STATEMENT;

    BEFORE EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.borrower_id MEMBER OF v_borrower_count THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Error - ' || :NEW.status);
        END IF;
    END BEFORE EACH ROW;

END;
```